# Deploy Scalatra on Heroku error

Tags: scala, deployment, heroku, scalatra

I followed the guide of deploying a Scalatra app on Heroku and I get the following error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: stage (similar: last-grep, set, last)
       [error] Expected '/'
       [error] Expected ':'
       [error] Not a valid key: stage (similar: state, target, tags)
       [error] stage
       [error]      ^
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the end I just looked through this complete example and made sure I had everything in place from there - https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.2/deployment/scalatra-heroku